# .rdlc and PDF - font overlaps horizontally/does not render correctly when printed

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Community

I'm facing problem in `rdlc`. i'm using (.rdlc) in window application to print report. 
Issue : (space between char)Fonts of report are getting overlap horizontally same issue also happens in export and Print.This issue facing after system format.
to fix this i'have tried all way like System Font set to 100%, replaced rdlc,printer driver,import all required fonts to systems(Arial-11pt).but still issue is exist.

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e1Lc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, I believe I found at least part of the answer to this problem. [As described in one of the comments here](http://vinay.inkeysolutions.com/2011/12/workarounds-for-ssrs-2008-font_1212.html), it can be fixed using [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2768741/visual-elements-are-displayed-incorrectly-when-you-connect-to-a-comput). However, the hotfix is no longer available for download.